# Jboss cli command for adding a nested xml element

Tags: xml, jboss, jvm, keycloak

We are using keycloak as Identity provider for our application. We need to configure  offlineSessions eviction policy in standalone-ha.xml file. So in `standalone-ha.xml` file we have an entry like bellow.

```
<distributed-cache name="offlineSessions">
</distributed-cache>
```

we need to change it to

```
<distributed-cache name="offlineSessions">
  <object-memory size="200"/>
</distributed-cache>
```

In JBoss cli there is a command `write-attribute` that will add an attribute to an existing element but here we need to add a nested element. Is there any command in JBoss cli for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add the [object memory resource](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/wildscribe/subsystem/infinispan/cache-container/distributed-cache/memory/object/index.html).

```
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=example/distributed-cache=offlineSessions/memory=object:add(size=200)
```